# How to download a file in Node.js

Tags: node.js, csv, download

I am trying to create a script to retrieve a file from a website in Node.js.

Here is how i am trying to make my script work :

1. Retrieve the download link from a CSV file (cycle the URLs if there are many)
2. Download the file that is at this link
3. Save the downloaded file locally

My code runs without any bug or warning. By that I mean the line "Download completed - " with the correct URL appears. A new file is correctly created at the specified location. The problem is that this file is always empty (0kb).

here is the code I have been able to put together :

```
const fs = require('fs');
const csv = require('csv');
const https = require('https');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const { parse } = require("csv-parse");

downloadAllFiles();

async function downloadAllFiles() {
        var FILE = //LOCATION OF THE CSV FILE;
        const parse = require('csv-parse/lib/sync');
        const data = fs.readFileSync(FILE);
        let records = parse(data, {columns: false,});

        \\Here is some more code to login to the website. The connection is successful.

        await downloadFile(records[0][0], records[0][1]);
};

function downloadFile(destinationPath, url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        https.get(url, (response) => {
            let filePath = //WHERE TO SAVE THE FILE;
            let stream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);

            response.on("error", reject);

            stream.on("finish", () => {
                stream.close();
                console.log("Download Completed - " + url);
                resolve();
            }).on("error", reject);

            response.pipe(stream);

        }).on("error", reject);
    });
};
```

I can't figure out why the file isn't being downloaded properly. Would anyone be able to help ?

Comment: Does the error print anything to console on node?

Comment: There is no error appearing on the console. just the message "Download Completed - " followed by the correct URL

Comment: @superamen based on the code, I think the step on the pupeteer seems there are no working, as the filedownload work as it's as I see. 2nd could be also the csv file is broken? Have you tried directly to download only using the hotlink url?

Also remember, when you want to download the file, it could be 403 because you use pupeteer to navigate and login. You can also request pupeteer to download the file, see https://www.scrapingbee.com/blog/download-file-puppeteer/

Comment: Why are you loading parse twice?  Once with this `const { parse } = require("csv-parse");` and once with this `const parse = require('csv-parse/lib/sync');`?

Comment: What's the bit about logging into the website in your code?  If that login is required BEFORE the `https.get()`, then you probably have to save the login cookie and pass it with the `https.get()` - otherwise the `https.get()` won't be logged in.

Comment: @jfriend00 The parsing being called twice is just a mistake. I will delete one of them, thanks for pointing that out. Yes, the login is made before the `https.get()`. I will try to find how to save the login cookie and pass it to the function and see if that works, thank you very much !

Comment: I would guess that you're getting a non-200 status back from the `https.get()` which you aren't checking for.  And, that status probably comes with no body which is why the request finishes, but your file is empty.  You need to check `res.statusCode`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are logging into the website before making your request, then probably that creates a login cookie and you need to grab that login cookie from the login process and include that cookie with the `https.get()` request you make afterwards.  If you do these http requests with a higher level library such as `axios()` or `got()`, you can use a cookie jar accessory with both of them to retain the cookies for you.  Those higher level libraries are also promise-based which will make the coding easier.

You also need to be checking `res.statusCode` to see if you're getting a 200 response before you try to write the response to a file.  I presume the reason you aren't getting any data in the file is you're not getting a 200 response.  Perhaps you're getting a 3xx or 4xx response that contain no body data and thus your file is empty.

You also don't need to manually close the stream because `.pipe()` will manage that for you.

Comment: Indeed I got "302" as a response when I checked for 'res.statusCode'.